# Processing following control

Tags: processing

Processing code as below:

```
int maxCircle = 200;
float minDistance=2;
float distance;
Circle [] circles= new Circle[maxCircle];


void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  smooth();
  for(int i=0;i<maxCircle;i++){
   circles[i] = new Circle(random(width),random(height),random(2,20));
  }
 }

 void draw(){
   background(255,255);
   for(int i=0;i<maxCircle;i++){
   circles[i].update(width,height);


 for(int j=0;j<maxCircle;j++){
  distance = dist(circles[i].x,circles[i].y,circles[j].x,circles[j].y);
  if(distance<minDistance){
    stroke(0,50);
    noFill();
    line(circles[i].x,circles[i].y,circles[j].x,circles[j].y);}}


circles[i].display();

 }

}

 void mouseMoved(){
   for(int i = 0; i<maxCircle;i++){
    circles[i].x+=(mouseX-circles[i].x)*.2;
    circles[i].y+=(mouseX-circles[i].y)*.2;}}




  class Circle{
      float x,y,vx,vy,r,speed;

  Circle(float tempx, float tempy, float tempr){  
     x=tempx;
     y=tempy;
     vx=random(-1,1);
     vy=random(-1,1);
     r=tempr;
    }

  void update(int w,int h){
   x+=vx;
   y+=vy;

   if(x<r || x>w-r){
     vx*=-1;};
   if(y<r || y>h-r){
     vy*=-1;};
    }


   void display(){
      fill(0,50);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x,y,r,r);
    }  

    }
```

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't the line function work?
2. How can i make circles move smoothly(respectively) following my mouse instead of squeezing into one point abruptly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Casey's work -- are you at UCLA?

Anyway -- the line() function *does* work.  Try increasing your minDistance to something more like 20, and you'll see lines.

Re: mouse following, you're telling *every* circle to move 20% of the distance to the mouse, every frame.  I'm not sure exactly what you want here; do you want only circles near the mouse to move with the mouse?  If so, apply a distance check to the mouse for each circle and only move the circle toward the mouse if it's within that distance.  Something like:

```
void mouseMoved() {
  float distance;
  for(int i = 0; i<maxCircle;i++){
    float mouseDist = dist(circles[i].x,circles[i].y,mouseX,mouseY);

    // move toward mouse only if < 100px from mouse
    if (mouseDist < 100) {
      circles[i].x+=(mouseX-circles[i].x)*.05;
      circles[i].y+=(mouseY-circles[i].y)*.05;
    }
  }
}
```